# forEach returns a string not an object

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Tomcat 7 with JDK7

```
class Product
    private java.util.List<OrderedProduct> childProducts; // with getter and setter
```

JSTL

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${sessionScope.products}">                          
    <c:forEach var="child" items="${product.childProducts}  ">                                                          
          <c:out value="${child}" />
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

The inital forEach returns objects I can call ${product.id} on, however child is always a string. The only mention of this online I found is missing ${} in forEach but I have those. Any other reasons JSTL would not return the actual object?

Comment: What do you mean by `child is always a string`? `c:out` prints out the `toString()` of whatever the object is.

Comment: the inner list is also a list of Product class

Comment: all of non collection values like id, this is what id gives me -> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not found on type java.lang.String

Comment: Can you show us the code that causes that? Also show us how you populate `childProducts`.

Comment: @user1889665, Do you have getter method of `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever you have is correct except the spacing in the **items="${product.childProducts}      ">**. There should not be any spacing after **}** and before **"**.

Try like this:

```
    <c:forEach var="product" items="${sessionScope.products}">                          
        <c:forEach var="child" items="${product.childProducts}">                                                          
              <c:out value="${child.id}" />
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Nope, not atleast in the sample code i tried. It complains the class "java.lang.String" does not have property....

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Just try one with spacing, you will see this issue.

Comment: @Prasad you are absolutely right when there is any space or any character after `#{}` then it will be converted to string by first calling `toString()` of the object and appending spaces in it. It's the correct answer.

Comment: it was that space at the end

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse [JSP Standard Tag Library (JSTL)](https://jstl.java.net/) with [Expression Language (EL)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el.htm). The former is a set of tags to be used in JSP and Facelets, while the latter is a expression that will seek for objects as attribute stored in page, request, session or application scope for your and use immediate or deferred evaluation to the elements in the view.

After understanding this, you can understand that calling `${child}` means retrieving the value of page context variable `child` that is retrieved from `${product.childProducts}`. It will return the `OrderedProduct child` in your view directly.

JSTL `<c:out value="${whatever}">` invokes the `toString` method of `whatever` object reference and will escape the String. In your case, `<c:out value="${child}" />` will invoke `child#toString()` and if `OrderedProduct` hasn't override `toString` method then it will use `Object#toString`.

> Any other reasons JSTL would not return the actual object?

From the above explanation, the question is completely wrong. You get the actual object and you should not use `<c:out value="${whatever} />` carelessly. Instead, just print out the necessary fields of your object. For example:

```html
<c:out value="${child.name}" />
```